# Zend Framework 1.12 and Wordpress redirects wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, zend-framework, redirect

I'm having some problems using zend framework 1.12 and wordpress at the same time..

I know the problem needs to be in the htaccess because zend framework and wordpress are working.

**The problem:**

if surf to `localhost/blog` it redirects me to the url `localhost/public_html/blog`. When that happens wordpress opens and says it can't find anything..

But if i open it with `localhost/blog/hello-world` (where hello-world stand for a post) it works like a charm.

How can i make sure that if i'm surfing to `localhost/blog` the index page of wordpress blog will show up and that i will not be redirected to `localhost/public_html/blog` -> "not found" page.

my htaccess in public_html:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and my htaccess in /public_html/blog/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks for reading and i hope someone can help me with this!

Greetings,

Cees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself so for the persons who are interested:

I placed the blog in /public_html/wordpress
But i put my links to: /blog

my htaccess in public_html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and my htaccess in /public_html/wordpress/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also changed my index.php in /public_html/index.php because i'm skipping the Zend bootstrap when /blog is called.

```
<?php

$aExplodedUri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


if($aExplodedUri[1] == 'blog')
{
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );

}
else
{
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();    
}
```

You also need to change wp-config file and add the follow lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.yoururl.nl/wordpress');
```

Good luck!

Greetz,

Cees

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your root **.htaccess** :

```
RewriteRule ^blog - [NC,L]
```

If a folder/file is found by the system, it will be used!

And remove this line from your **blog/.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```